# Memory Management in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I wanna ask if I allocated an instance variable for private use in that class, should i release it immediately on site, or i can depend on **dealloc** function. (because maybe i will need it on other function) ?

```
//Player.h
@interface Player : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray * objectArray;
}

- (void)awake;
- (void)add;

@end

//Player.m
@implementation Player : NSObject
{
    -(id) init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self !=  nil ){
            [self awake];
            [self add];
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void) awake {
        objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //is it cause leakage?
        [objectArray addObject:@"foobar"];
    }
    - (void) add {
        [objectArray addObject:@"foobar2"];
    }
    - (void) dealloc {
        [objectArray release];
        [super dealloc];
    }
}

@end
```

or should i using property to set the **objectArray** iVar?

```
//Player.h
@interface Player : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray * objectArray;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray* objectArray;

- (void)awake;
- (void)add;

@end

//Player.m
@implementation Player : NSObject
{
    -(id) init {
        self = [super init];
        if (self !=  nil ){
            [self awake];
            [self add];
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void) awake {
        self.objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init autorelease]; //cause leakage?
        [objectArray addObject:@"foobar"];
    }
    - (void) add {
        [objectArray addObject:@"foobar2"];
    }
    - (void) dealloc {
        [objectArray release];
        [super dealloc];
    }
}

@end
```

if both of them doesn't cause a leakage, what type should i use? 
should i always set **iVar** property, and access **iVar** value with **self**  even if i only want to use it in this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that memory will leak in your first example because you are not sending `release` to the previously set instance variable (if it already existed).

This is why you *should* use property setters - they handle all of this stuff for you.

Also, since you are obtaining ownership of the instance variable through the property (which is defined with the `retain` keyword), you will **definitely** leak memory if you don't send the instance variable the `-release` message in your `-dealloc` method.

So the verdict is that you should use the ***second*** example, not the first.

Comment: but if I use property setters like self.objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init autorelease]. i will have to use an autorelease function? i thought autorelease should not practice it in code.

Comment: @Lunayo That is perfectly fine, because your property will `retain` it. You should still send it the `-release` message in `-dealloc` however.

Comment: so if use the second example, i won't have to worry about 'release' in the any function except the '-dealloc' method?

Comment: As I stated in my own answer, I would not use properties in this case and just allocate the array in -init and release it in -dealloc. Declaring a property in your header provides a point of access to your array for other objects, which may not be what you really want. Additionally, you're using an NSAutoreleasePool (by calling -autorelease) for no benefit at all.

Answer (score 2):

I like to take the stance that if the instance variable should not be visible outside of the class then it should not be implemented as a property.  But it's a personal thing that other developers may not agree with.

Either way you would need to release the objectArray in your classes dealloc method - which is what you're currently doing.

However you need to be careful with your awake method - if it's invoked multiple times then objectArray is leaked.  This is the downside of not using properties.  A use of self.objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] here would have released the previous object.

Comment: if I use the first example, then the iVar objectArray should release in -awake or both in -awake and -dealloc ?

Comment: You would need to release in both - or simply just alloc it once and for all in your init and then release in dealloc.

Comment: @mmccomb->I think you pointed out yourself the downside of not using properties. While it does seem "stupid" in some sense to use a property for an iVar not used outside the class, it can make memory management easier if you treat all iVars the same, so you can just use the same pattern everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should only declare properties in your header if other objects are allowed to use them. There is no good reason why you would provide an -add: method (as in your example) that adds something to your array while also providing a getter for your array so other objects can manipulate it directly. It's called encapsulation.

If you do want to have the benefits of generated getters/setters for your implementation file, you can always use a class continuation (a nameless category) inside your implementation file and include your property declarations there. That way you get real, auto-generated properties that are only visible to your class' implementation.

Personally, I wouldn't use any getter or setter methods in your example. Just allocate the NSArray in your -init and release it in -dealloc. If this -awake method of yours might be called multiple times, just add an `[objectArray removeAllObjects]` call and you're sure to have an empty array without worrying about memory management.

Comment: that is an example, if i need to add an object to objectArray the whole time, is release only in -dealloc will not cause leakage?

Comment: and if like you say, i allocate objectArray in -init method. where should i release it? only in -dealloc?

Comment: You only leak memory if you allocate something and never release it. If you need an allocated object only within the scope of a method, you release it before the method returns. If you don't, you allocated something and after the method, there is no reference to it anymore and you cannot release it. In your case however, you want the array (or other instance variables) to live as long as your Player object lives. Therefore, you allocate it in -init and release it in -dealloc. No leak there.

Comment: Ok so if the -awake method can be called multiple times, i should change the code in awake `if (arrayObject != nil ) arrayObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` ?

Comment: Exactly. But its better practice to allocate it in -init, because it only gets called once. (Actually, there's nothing preventing you from calling -init again, but you should never, never, never do that)